# Dump the CKAN database and Load it in another CKAN instance

Tags: python-2.7, migration, ckan

I have made several unsuccessful attempts to load the CKAN database into another CKAN instance in a different host.

My workflow is the following:

## A> Extract the db dump from the production host (host_p)

```
paster db dump -c /etc/ckan/ckan_p_instance/production.ini instance_p_db_dump.sql
```

## B> Copy the dumped database file to my new host (host_t)

## C> Activate the CKAN virtual environment

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/ckan_t_instance/bin/activate
```

## D> Clean the existing CKAN database in host_t

```
paster db clean -c /etc/ckan/spatial_hub/development.ini
```

## E> Load the dumped file into the CKAN host_t instance.

```
paster db load -c /etc/ckan/spatial_hub/development.ini ~/instance_p_db_dump.sql
```

## F> I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/spatial_hub/bin/paster", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/spatial_hub/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/spatial_hub/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/spatial_hub/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/spatial_hub/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 238, in command
    self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/spatial_hub/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 315, in load
    pg_cmd = self._postgres_load(dump_path)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/spatial_hub/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 290, in _postgres_load
    self._run_cmd(pg_cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/spatial_hub/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 297, in _run_cmd
    raise SystemError('Command exited with errorcode: %i' % retcode)
SystemError: Command exited with errorcode: 2
```

I am not sure how to interpret the above error so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What versions of CKAN and PostgreSQL are you running?

Comment: Put in a line 'print pg_cmd' in cli.py before line 290 and let us know what it says (changing the value of your PG_PASSWORD to Xs). And you do have your postgres password set in your sqlalchemy.url in /etc/ckan/spatial_hub/development.ini file, don't you?

Comment: Thanks for replying.

CKAN version: 2.5.2, PSQL version 9.5.3, sqlalchemy.url has been set properly in the configuration file.
@DRead Adding the print statement in cli.py the following is printed:

export PGPASSWORD=XXXXXX && psql -U ckan_spatialhub -h localhost -d ckan_spatialhub -f /home/username/ckan_db_dump.sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your running into [a known bug](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/2952), where special characters in the password are not properly escaped. The `paster db dump` and `load` commands are going to be deprecated for this and other reasons. The official suggestion is to use PostgreSQL's own tools (e.g. [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html) and [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgrestore.html)) in combination with `paster db upgrade` (which will be kept) instead.

As a short-term workaround, make sure that your password does not contain characters that are special for your shell.

**Update:** The CKAN documentation has been updated with information on [how to dump and load the CKAN database using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/database-management.html#dumping-and-loading-databases-to-from-a-file).

Comment: Thanks Florian,

I can confirm that my password contains special characters.

If the plan is to deprecate 'db dump' and 'db load' I will give the 'pg_dump', 'pg_restore' and 'db upgrade' a shot.

Any useful resources on how to take the PSQL workflow forward?

Thanks again

Comment: @Dimitris Glad I could help! The plan is to update the CKAN documentation with examples on how to do DB migrations using PostgreSQL tools, but that hasn't been implemented, yet.

Comment: Hi,
This is just to confirm that changing the CKAN db user password to alphanumeric characters fixed the problem. The database has been transferred successfully to the new host using 'db dump', 'db clean', and 'db load'. Thanks again.